# Dendrogram edge (branch) colors to match tip (leaf) colors (ape package)

Tags: r, dendrogram, phylogeny, dendextend

I'm trying to add color to the edges (lines) of a phylogeny-type plot in R using the plot.phylo command from the ape package. This example is for a "fan" type plot, though I expect the approach would be the same with a "phylogram type" or whatever.

```
library('ape')
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(as.phylo(hc), type="fan")
```

Adding colour to the tips (labels) based on a set of groups is no problem with the tip.color option combined with cutree command.

```
hc.cuts <- cutree(hc, k=5)
plot(as.phylo(hc), type="fan", tip.color=rainbow(5)[hc.cuts])
```

The edge.color option defines the colors of the edges, but not in a logincal manner when many colours are desired.

```
plot(as.phylo(hc), type="fan", tip.color=rainbow(5)[hc.cuts], edge.color=rainbow(5)[hc.cuts])
```

However, I would like the edges to match the terminal tip colours once that branch of the dendrogram is destined for a given group. In the given example, towards the red & blue groups, the first levels of edges would stay black (as it's headed for two groups: red and blue), but edges beyond this would be colored the same as the eventual tip color.

I suspect the key lies in figuring out the ordering of the $edge values in the as.phylo object, but I can't figure it myself. Thanks.

Comment: For the off-chance that you won't get a satisfying answer, I'd like to let you know that there are also the [dendextend](https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend) package and the [ggdendro](https://github.com/andrie/ggdendro) package, maybe one of the two can help you out. They're both quite new, too.

Comment: Hi Maj,
the ggdendro by Andrie was the first package to help have a dendrogram plot in ggplot2. It was limited in that it didn't take into account various graphical parameters of the branches/nodes/leaves of the tree. The dendextend has a function called "as.ggdend" (which is actually a fork of ggdendro), which does take into account further graphical parameters of the tree. You can see more about it here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#ggplot2-integration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @maj suggested in a comment, [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html) can help you out if you don't mind using that package. It is very flexible and has extensive documentation and vignettes.

Here's an example minimally adapted from the dendextend [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/FAQ.html).

```
# install.packages("dendextend")
# install.packages("circlize")

library(dendextend)
library(circlize)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

num_clades <- 5

dend <- dend %>% 
  color_branches(k=num_clades, col=rainbow) %>% 
  color_labels(k=num_clades, col=rainbow)

par(mar = rep(0, 4))
circlize_dendrogram(dend, dend_track_height = 0.8)
```

It outputs

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. I didn't know about the 'dendextend' package. Lovely!